# SQL multiple were clause to return only one value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables which im joining based on a the dms_doc doc_id. So each document can have many departments and contracts (stored in another two tables but the information in those tables is not relevant for this query).

```
dms_docs     dms_departments     dms_contracts
id           id                  id
             doc_id              doc_id
             dep_id              con_id
```

So far I have the following query:

```
SELECT dms_docs.*, dms_departments.doc_id, dms_departments.dep_id, dms_contracts.doc_id, dms_contracts.con_id
FROM dms_docs 
JOIN dms_departments 
    ON dms_docs.id=dms_departments.doc_id
JOIN dms_contracts
    ON dms_docs.id=dms_contracts.doc_id
WHERE dep_id = 10
AND (con_id  = 1 OR con_id = 2)
```

So each document can have many contracts(con_id) and each document can have many departments(dep_id), the problem the above query produces is if one document has many contracts and/or departments it returns the document multiple times.

For example in the above query a document belongs to contract 1 and contract 2  so it is returned 2 times. How can I return the result only once if it matches any of the criteria I pass to it? I'm guessing I need to use DISTINCT in here somewhere but I'm not sure how to do this correctly.

Comment: if you show the con_id, you are going to get two rows for the document associated to two contracts. Are you trying to avoid this?

Comment: @mucio if one document belongs to contract.id 1 and contract.id 2 they both get returned, I only want one to be returned. The idea behind this is the user can select which documents they want to return so they could ask for all documents that belong to contract 1, 5, 6, 7 and if a document belongs to 3 of those contracts, my current query will return the document 3 times, I want it only returning once.

Comment: then change your select statement into `SELECT distinct dms_docs.*`, in this way you will see only the document info and no duplicates

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanted document information, I would suggests `exists`.  However, you are also asking for info from the other tables.  For that, use `group by` and `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT d.*, group_concat(distinct de.dep_id) as dep_ids,
       group_concat(distinct c.con_id) as con_ids
FROM dms_docs d JOIN
     dms_departments de
     ON d.id = de.doc_id JOIN
     dms_contracts c
     ON d.id = c.doc_id
WHERE dep_id = 10 AND (con_id IN (1, 2))
GROUP BY d.doc_id;
```